# JSF 2.2 : How to handle a Coinbase callback?

Tags: callback, httprequest, jsf-2.2, coinbase-api

Using Coinbase, I need to design an interface for the callback.

My application uses JSF 2.2, and I do not really know how to intercept the Coinbase request.

Using servlet, I could retrieve the contents of the request in a doGet, but with JSF I'm stuck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF framework itself is a servlet. Everything you need to get from request you can get in JSF through Faces API.
Example, to get the request object:

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                     .getExternalContext().getRequest();
```

and so on.
Otherwise you can always create a custom servlet and map it in web.xml next to Faces servlet.

Comment: Yes, but how to call it in my "front" XHTML/JSF file w/o any user action ? (it's a callback)

Comment: Well, you could create method which can be called on page load with f:viewAction element on jsf page, but i suggest to use a custom servlet.